# Get average of a column classified on specific dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a *table* of the following format:
**DATETIME**  **TEMPERATURE1**  **HUMIDITY1**

where records (datetime) have an interval of 2 hours.
I want to get a minimum, average and max of each week.
I can imagine making the following *view* for 12 months:

```
SELECT 1 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-01%' UNION
SELECT 2 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-02%' UNION
SELECT 3 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-03%' UNION
SELECT 4 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-04%' UNION
SELECT 5 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-05%' UNION
SELECT 6 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-06%' UNION
SELECT 7 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-07%' UNION
SELECT 8 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-08%' UNION
SELECT 9 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-09%' UNION
SELECT 10 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-10%' UNION
SELECT 11 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-11%' UNION
SELECT 12 AS month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
  FROM TandRH WHERE DATE(dt) LIKE '2014-12%'
```

1. How can I do it for 52 weeks?
2. Is there any smarter solution for the 12 months?
3. I also though about making a new table and updating it every week, but this stores the same data twice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a question about weeks and months.  I'll answer the one for months.  You want to use `group by`:

```
SELECT month(date) as month, min(t1) AS mn, avg(t1) AS av, max(t1) AS mx
FROM TandRH 
WHERE year(date) = 2014
GROUP BY month(date);
```

You would do something similar for week, using `weekofyear()` instead of `month()`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like this: SELECT strftime('%m', dt) as month, avg(t1) FROM TandRH WHERE strftime('%Y', TandRH.dt) = '2014' GROUP BY month;